# Hadoop: datanode not starting on slave

Tags: hadoop

I have two VMs setup with Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to setup Hadoop multinode, but after executing `hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh`I see following process on my master:

```
20612 DataNode
20404 NameNode
20889 SecondaryNameNode
21372 Jps
```

However, there is nothing in the slave. Also when I do `hdfs dfsadmin -report`, I only see:

```
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 10.222.208.221:9866 (master)
Hostname: master
```

**I checked logs, my start-dfs.sh does not even try to start datanode on my slave.**
I am using following configuration:

```
#/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.222.208.221  master
10.222.208.68   slave-1
```

changed hostanme in /etc/hostname in respective systems
Also, I am able to ping slave-1 from master system and vice-versa using ping.

## /hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

#hadoop/etc/hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///hadoop/data/namenode</value>
        <description>NameNode directory</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///hadoop/data/datanode</value>
        <description>DataNode directory</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
 </configuration>
```

## /hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>master:9001</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

I have also added master and slave-1 in `/hadoop/etc/master` and `/hadoop/etc/slaves`on both my master and slave system.

I have also tried cleaning data/* and then `hdfs namenode -format` before `start-dfs.sh`, still the problem persists.

Also, I have Network adapter setting marked as Bridged adapter.

Any possible reason datanode not starting on slave?

Comment: `mapred.job.tracker` doesn't exist in Hadoop2, however that's not a DFS problem... Can you add your log output to the question? Also are you sure you want 3 replicas on 2 datanodes? FWIW, Apache Ambari has an automated Hadoop installer

Comment: I've been beating my head on this all day.  Would love an answer.  I have one more datanode than the OP, but otherwise my config looks nearly identical.  No idea why start-dfs.sh is starting a datanode on my namenode.

Answer (score 4):

Can't claim to have the answer, but I found this ["start-all.sh" and "start-dfs.sh" from master node do not start the slave node services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910606/start-all-sh-and-start-dfs-sh-from-master-node-do-not-start-the-slave-node-s)

Changed my slaves file to workers file and everything clicked in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using hadoop-2.x.x or above, so, try this configuration. And by default **masters** file( `hadoop-2.x.x/etc/hadoop/masters`) won't available on hadoop-2.x.x onwards.

hadoop-2.x.x/etc/hadoop/**core-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

~/etc/hadoop/**hdfs-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///hadoop/data/namenode</value>
    <description>NameNode directory</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    <description>DataNode directory</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

~/etc/hadoop/**mapred-site.xml:**

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

~/etc/hadoop/**yarn-site.xml:**

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>master</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

~/etc/hadoop/**slaves**

```
slave-1
```

copy all the above configured file from master and replace it on slave on this path `hadoop-2.x.x/etc/hadoop/.`

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I did not realize that the "workers" was called "slaves" in hadoop 2.x.